# Prevent submission unless all fields are filled asp.net and c# (Multiple choice quiz)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a multiple choice quiz whereby users will answer the questions and will be presented with a score upon submission, I am using required field validators to present a message if they do not answer one of the questions, however the system will still calculate their score even if I have not completed all the questions when hitting submit.
I need to be able to stop submission until all radio button lists are completed but i'm not sure how to do this.
My code is here:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel1" runat="server" Text="Question 1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q1requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 1 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel2" runat="server" Text="Question 2"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q2requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList2" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 2 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="QLabel3" runat="server" Text="Question 3"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q3requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList3" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 3 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel4" runat="server" Text="Question 4"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q4requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList4" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 4 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel5" runat="server" Text="Question 5"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList5" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q5requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList5" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 5 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel6" runat="server" Text="Question 6"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList6" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q6requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList6" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 6 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel7" runat="server" Text="Question 7"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList7" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q7requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList7" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 7 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel8" runat="server" Text="Question 8"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList8" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q8requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList8" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 8 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel9" runat="server" Text="Question 9"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList9" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q9requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList9" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 9 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="QLabel10" runat="server" Text="Question 10"></asp:Label>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList10" runat="server"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 1*" Value="Incorrect 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 2*" Value="Correct" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 3*" Value="I" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="*Answer 4*" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Q10requiredvalidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList10" CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="Ensure question 10 is completed"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Final Answers" OnClick="Submit_Click" Visible="true" />

    <script runat="server">
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int score = 0;
            List<RadioButtonList> list = new List<RadioButtonList>() { RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, RadioButtonList3, RadioButtonList4, RadioButtonList5, RadioButtonList6, RadioButtonList7, RadioButtonList8, RadioButtonList9, RadioButtonList10 };
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                if (element.SelectedValue == "Correct")
                {
                    score++;
                }

            }
            Response.Write("you scored: " + score);
            Button1.Visible = false;
        }
    </script>


</asp:Content>
```

Before hitting submit:

[image]

After Hitting submit when no answers are filled:

[image]

My submit button dissapears like it is supposed to but i want to be able to stop it from being submitted and the score output until all questions are answered.

New to all these so sorry if this seems easy or stupid.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a problem in your code, it will not work until all the radio buttons are not checked because of fieldValidators or you want something else?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid, i have addes screenshots to show what i mean